# how do i find the city & country with the highest number of unique customers, also the count of unique players?

Tags: pandas, data-science

[![dataset[image: ][1]]][2]

how to find the country with highest number of unique customers?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the data as text, not as a picture. E.g. try `df.to_dict()` and post in a block between triple backticks (```). Show both input *and* expected output. Also, show us what you have tried so far, and why your attempt isn't giving you the result that you expect. See: [Research Effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Clearly state your goal: the Q in the title does not align properly with the Q in the text.

Comment: @subham singh what is players ?

Comment: I think its the customer-id, can you tell me how to find the 
city with most number of unique customers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try:

```
df=df.groupby('COUNTRY')['IDCUSTOMER'].nunique()

#or if you want to group by country and city

df=df.groupby(['COUNTRY','CITY'[)['IDCUSTOMER'].nunique()
```